# stereo in Qt using Open GL

Tags: qt, opengl, stereo-3d

I am trying to make a stereo window in Qt. I seem to be lost in the interaction of Qt and OpenGL.

I have set the stereo context in my GL initialization code

```
QGLFormat fmt
fmt.setStereo(true)
```

and when I check the value, it comes back true.

I then draw into the `GL_BACK_LEFT` and `GL_BACK_RIGHT` buffers  (I have also tried just `GL_LEFT` and `GL_RIGHT`) but the resultant scene contains both sets of polygons.

I know that my hardware (*NVIDIA Quadro FX 3500*) supports stereo in a window, since other applications (for which I do not have source code) work fine.

Does this symptom seem familiar to anybody, enough so that it might be obvious what stupid mistake I am making?

Windows XP, Qt 4.4.2, MS Studio 2005

Answer (score 4):

*It never fails.

Ask a question, and figure out the answer within minutes of asking for help.  Oh well, hopefully somebody else might benefit.*

I was doing this

```
fmt.setStereo(true)
```

but not this

```
setFormat(fmt);
```

now it seems to work more like I want to to.

Comment: I have an application running OpenGL together with Qt. I want to be able to render in stereo mode too, do you have some references where I can get a simple example on what and how to set up Qt to render in stereo mode? Or is it as simple as setting the GLFormat stereo to true?